# Using CA certificate in Java to connect to a Vault

Tags: java, hashicorp-vault, cacerts

I would like to retrieve credentials from Vault.

In that context, I found this. https://bettercloud.github.io/vault-java-driver/.

But to connect to Vault, instead of the token, I have CA certificate.

I found a few examples mentioned in the above link, but I found no example using certificate.

I did not work with any CA Certificate before in code.

Could anyone please help here, regarding how to make use of the certificate? Thanks.

Comment: What about the `sslPemFile` method described on the page you linked?